# Is it possible to use recursion to solve the following problem? I am using while and for loops right now

Tags: python, recursion

Write a function make_human_move(current_player, board), which does the following:

Print out the player's shape (e.g. if the player shape is 'X', the function prints "X's move").
Asks the human player for his/her move. The message asked is "Enter row and column [0 - 2]: ".
A move consists of two integer values separated by a space (e.g. '0 0'). You can assume the input will always be two integer values separated by a space.
The function checks if the move is valid or not.
A valid move is when the integer value is between 0 and 2 for both row and column values.
It also makes sure that a valid location on the board is empty (i.e. currently an empty space character ' ').
If a move is invalid, the function prints "Illegal move. Try again." and repeats from step 2.
Once a valid move is entered, the board state is updated.

This is how I am doing it right now.

```
def make_human_move(current_player, board):
    """Given a board state and the human piece ('O' or 'X')
       ask the player for a location to play in. Repeat until a
       valid response is given. Then make the move, i.e., update the board by setting the chosen cell to the player's piece.       
    """
    print(current_player + "'s move")
    user_input = input("Enter row and column [0 - 2]: ")
    input_list = user_input.split()
    state = True
    while state:
        restart = False
        for i in input_list:
            if (int(i) > 2 or int(i) < 0) or (board[int(input_list[0])][int(input_list[1])] != " "):
                print("Illegal move. Try again.")
                user_input = input("Enter row and column [0 - 2]: ")
                input_list = user_input.split()
                restart = True
                break
        if restart:
            continue
        else:
            board[int(input_list[0])][int(input_list[1])] = current_player
            break
```

Comment: `If a move is invalid, the function prints "Illegal move. Try again." and repeats from step 2.` What is step 2? You did not number the steps.

Comment: I suggest posting this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ; there are several things that could be improved. For example, you use a boolean variable `state` as the condition for your while loop, but then you never change the value of `state`, and end up having to break out of the loop with `break`. You also have a variable called `restart` which looks like it wants to be the loop condition, but it is not. The `continue` statement is not doing anything here, as it is at the end of the loop body, and loops always continue by default.

Comment: I have submitted the code on codereview.stackexchange.com. Yeah, I know there was no need to use ```state```, I could have just used ```True```, I forgot to edit that before submitting the question. The ```restart``` variable is used to reach the ```continue statement```, the first break statement is used to break out of the for loop so ```continue``` is not a part of the for loop but is a part of the ```while``` loop, we could have avoided using is by using ```if not restart:``` and then using ```board[int(input_list[0])][int(input_list[1])] = current_player``` and then ```break```.

Comment: But at the moment continue is doing a task here and is not here for no reason.